# Input button in firefox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

(I've changed the input tag with a button tag.)
This probably is a stupid question, but here goes. I have an input button like this:

```
<button type="submit"
       id="choice"
       value="Escolher" 
       onClick="javascript:makeChanges()">
```

It works well in IE, but in firefox it just doesn't do anything; there are no errors, no behavior what so ever.

My  "makeChanges()" function does the following:

```
var selObj = document.getElementById('opiniao');    
var selIndex = selObj.selectedIndex;
var str = selObj.options[selIndex].text +'&random='+(new Date()).getTime();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","writeSettings2.php?text="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
history.go(0);
}
```

If i put for isntance an alert on the call like:

```
<button type="submit"
           id="choice"
           value="Escolher" 
           onClick="alert('Hello')">
```

The button works, but it dosent when i try to call the javascript function.

Comment: Look in the Firebug console for any JS errors, if it's not working there should be some feedback as to *why*.

Comment: Have you tried ditching the "javascript:" in your onclick attribute?  There's no need to specify that you're putting a script element in there.

Comment: the input is of type submit. without a form, firefox doesnt know what to submit.

Comment: @Victor: Your comment reads like an answer. Consider posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="submit" />` is for submitting form data. Without `<form>` firefox doesn't know where or how the form should be submitted, so it doesn't submit.

If you want to use a button without a form, you can use the `<button>` tag.

Comment: Actually a <button> defaults to type="submit" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<input type="button" id="choice" value="Escolher" onClick="makeChanges()" />
```

what is your javascript? maybe there is a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some context about your code around this input element?  Is it in a form (doesn't sound like it)?  The "submit" input type needs to be in a form...can you just change it to a button input element instead?

```
<input type="button" id="choice" value="Escolher" onClick="javascript:makeChanges()">
```

Comment: Your questions should be comments to the original question, not parts of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The input is of type submit. Which indicates to submit a form. Without a form, Firefox doesnt know what to submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the type as "submit", browsers will attempt to post data to the enclosing <form> element's "action" attribute. You can disable this by adding "return false;" to your onclick handler. As others have said, "button" is the more appropriate type to use in this case. The below bare-bones example works for me:

```
&lt;input type="button" onClick="javascript:alert('hello');" /&gt;
```

Do you perhaps have NoScript installed in Firefox? Normally, file:// is not allowed to execute JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it worked ok in Firefox 3.  On the following HTML.  Check if your function is defined.  Or maybe it is your Firefox version?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function makeChanges(){
    alert('hi');
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="submit"
       id="choice"
       value="Escolher"
       onClick="javascript:makeChanges()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where and how do you define makeChanges()?  That seems to me likely to be the problem.  Or that makeChanges() is (unexpectedly) not having any effect.  I'd try adding an alert to it or tracking it in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

indeed this doesnt work on firefox (but works on IE, Chrome):

```
input type="button" value="Show Results" onClick="javascript:show()"
```

the solution is just put the javascript code inside the `onClick`, for instance:

```
input type="button" value="Show Results" onclick="document.getElementById('dsp').value=1;sertificatesStatsForm.submit();"
```